# java script for getting total price based on selected value from drop dowv

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a code in js where i have three feilds in a form

one is the price that is dynamic and other is the drop down in which i had ten values from 1 to 10  I want whenever I select option from dropdown i should get the total price base on the unit price

any kind of help appreciated

Comment: It would help so much to see the mark-up you're working with.

Comment: `JavaScript` is usually written as crunched together, not "java script". However, you should replace the `java` + `script` tags with the JavaScript one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `onchange` to your drop down and have it call a javascript function that does the calculation and sets the new value of the field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recalculate()
    {
        var f = document.forms.myform;
        f.cost.value = f.price.value * f.qty.value;
    }
</script>

<form action="doStuff" method="post" id="myform">
    <p>Price<input type="text" id="price"/></p>
    <p>Quantity
    <select id="qty" onChange="recalculate()">
        <option id="0">0</option>
        <option id="1">1</option>
        <option id="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <p>Cost<input type="text" id="cost"/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if I exactly understand what you want, but i tried write some code. You can test is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2QnL/1/)

so html markup can look something like that:

```
<input type="text" id="priceId" value="5" />
<select id="priceTypeId" name="priceType">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ...
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>

</select>

<input type="text" id="resultId" />
```

and jQuery functions for this are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#priceTypeId').change(function() {
      $('#resultId').val(  $('#priceTypeId').val() *  $('#priceId').val() );
   });
});
```

If you have any question, I'll try to answer quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure that he's *using* jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use some thig like these:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function FieldOnChange()
    {
    // put logic here use document.getElementByID('FieldID').value;
    }

    </script>

    <form>

    <select name='title' onchange='javascript:FieldOnChange();'>

    <option value='1'>1</option>

    <option value='2'>2</option>

    <option value='3'>3</option>
    ...
    </select>

    <!-- rest of your form -->

    </form>
```